# Genetically preventing a rebellion on a generation ship

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, genetics, generation-ships

In the year 21--, a crew of 100 sets out from Earth on the good ship *Tenzing Norgay*, bound for Epsilon Eridani. The journey is estimated to take . . . well, quite some time, given that it was calculated that the time spent to engineer a significantly faster propulsion system (compared to the technology of the day) would negate the benefits of going at the faster speed, and would end up costing too much more.<sup>1</sup> This means that the crew is stuck with using a ship outfitted with the Rockaway Plastopedic Thrustomatic<sup>TM</sup> <sup>2</sup> engines, making the trip take at least 250 years - far more than twice the lifespan of a normal human. It was also decided, to the crew's dismay, to not pursue suspended animation technology, thanks to budget cuts.

The one thing that the make of the ship *did* foresee was that a future generation might not be too happy about having to live and die in a ship, without ever stepping foot on a planet or doing anything besides get ready to reproduce and die. There is a very real threat of a person (or a group of people) hijacking the ship some day, and moving it to some nearby system. The computers are always on autopilot, but there's always a way to hack them.

The government decides to go with a foolproof method: using genetics to make sure that future generations on the ship will not rebel, using in vitro fertilization onboard via automatic systems. This is all very well and good, but I, the creator of the story, need to come up with a plausible explanation. I can imagine a few ideas, but they're not too good; they all boil down to neural modifications - changing genes to influence the brain. I'm no neurologist, but this doesn't sound feasible.

How can genetics be used to quell a rebellion before it begins?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Please, *please* don't dispute this. I think I can find a way to justify this, no matter what objections are made.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> The Rockaway Plastopedic Thrustomatic is a trademark of Rockaway Blastopedic Industries, soon to be of Epsilon Eridani.</sup>

Comment: I'm not good enough on neuroscience to actually answer your question. But a new generation comes about 20-25 years. So 250 years are, at least 10 generations born on-board the ship. The required skills to hack the system are probably hard to come by in a confined system. Furthermore the Space is mostly empty, even if you could, where would you go? No, I'd be more worried that they decide to STAY in the ship starting from the 5th of 6th generation. And how is the birthrate planned? 100 people ranging from 25 to 65 years old. So about 25 women who can bear children. You could end with 5 people.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin I'm imagining that they're taking a route near enough to other stars that it would be possible to turn the ship to a different destination, closer at a given point than the intended one. Hacking would be hard to come by, but some crew members would have to be computer-savvy, to some degree. Regarding birthrate - non-human birth has been perfected (i.e. machines can essentially give birth) - that's for another question, though.

Comment: And why would they want to leave the ship? They don't know anything else. Some crew might be computer-savvy, but maybe not enough to understand how the protection was done. And you can't have an AI ensuring that they do not try to use evolution to recreate the appropriate knowledge?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Like I said, they would rather go somewhere nearer, where they could actually reach a star system, as opposed to journeying through space for their entire life. And the voyage lasts for 250 years. Odds are that someone will find a way to hack the computer.

Comment: What is the purpose and what are the responsibilities of the crew?

Comment: @DanSmolinske They simply go about their lives, eating, sleeping, socializing (to some degree) and doing small bits of maintenance, none of which requires, say, exiting the craft.

Comment: I really don't see why genetics is necessary at all. Why not just make the ship in-navigable. Once they take off, they cannot stop it.

Comment: Sorry - are they colonists? Do they need to do maintenance? What's the point of having a crew? Asking since some methods of control might prevent them from their assigned duties.

Comment: @Jimmy360 How could you make it impossible to navigate?

Comment: @DanSmolinske They are colonists, yes. Maintenance consists of fixing various systems - electrical, plumbing, etc. They don't directly perform maintenance on propulsion systems; robots do that.

Comment: @HDE226868 No controls: they cannot steer or turn the ship i.e. once it starts going, it doesn't stop

Comment: @Jimmy360 Oh, you mean it's automated. Yes, to some extent. Again, though, if the computer controlling this could be hacked, then, that could change.

Comment: 100 people sounds [awfully small](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_population#MVP_and_extinction). Don't forget your [effective population size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_population_size), especially after a few generations of inbreeding...

Comment: Put lithium in their water -- problem goes away.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That seems to be a very rampant bee in some bonnets on this site, sorry. Humans on a space trip will have modern medicine, no diseases, no natural catastrophes, and can also manage any genetic disorder long before it becomes a problem. It's just some very simple genetic testing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem with genetic modification isn't going to appear during the trip, but rather once they reach the destination. A group which has been modified or selected to be docile and relatively apathetic is not going to be the best choice of people to deal with unknown and potentially dangerous colonizing situations.

Face it, humans being tough and pretty ornery is the recipe for our evolutionary success despite ice ages, sabre tooth tigers, mega volcanoes and pretty much everything else that has been thrown at us to date. What you really need is some way to redirect that sort of aggression and problem solving ability without wreaking the ship. While you might get a large fraction of people zones out by having an on board FaceBook server, you would  probably need something more constructive.

I would suggest some sort of VR "game" which is based on the sorts of observations and knowledge available to the designers before the ship set off, to allow people to "train" for the day the ship arrives. Each generation gets more detail as the ship approaches the target and more detailed observations and information gets added to the "game". If there is the space available, a "holodeck" sort of arrangement can also be added for some real life physical training action as well.

Comment: This seems the most reasonable answer: **don't fight it, because it will be needed later; just give it some other, safe outlet.** Heck, why not have a place (some sort of forum, perhaps?) where people can ask questions and get answers on hypothetical scenarios, to get them to think through various eventualities, and give them a creative outlet at the same time? You could additionally award some sort of points for good contributions, and detract points for bad contributions. These points could perhaps also translate to having various privileges on the forum itself.

Comment: RE: "Once they reach their destination" -- If you make the docility is non-permanent -- (i.e. just put lithium in their water) -- this problem goes away.  (i.e. when they hit their destination -- there will no longer be lithium in their water, they will stop being docile.) -- +1 for VR game though. :-)

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 If the children have no exposure to people who are not docile, wouldn't they have no chance whatsoever to adjust to the sudden lack of docility in both themselves and their peers?

Answer (score 8):

### Rerouting isn't an option for non-fantasy engines

For all currently feasible propulsion options and realistic physics, *movement* doesn't require energy, but *acceleration* does. A trip from A to B spends half of fuel/energy accelerating and half of it decelerating; and the fuel/energy amount spent influences only the speed, not how far they will go. Boring, but with rather interesting implications.

1. A simple stop in the exact middle means that you need twice as much fuel/energy than a non-stop rule. Which you likely don't have, since fuel is most likely 90%-99% of your ship mass, and taking double fuel isn't really an option.
2. Once you have done the main acceleration, the course is pretty much set in stone, and you'd only have enough fuel to stop. If the colonists rebel and reprogram the computer, the only thing they can do differently is either to stop elsewhere along the same line - in the middle of empty space, or alter the course to some other location where they'll only be able to stop by crashing into it at Ludicrous Speed (tm), annihilating the ship and possibly causing something similar to the dinosaur extinction event that happened on Earth.

Of course, a story can make different rules, but these can cause interesting situations even without deviating from reality.

Comment: If only they would've stopped at the chemists for a bag of peanuts first, they could've told them just how mindbogglingly huge space is, and how that's a *Really Bad Idea* (TM).

Comment: Theoretically, some good piloting can decelerate a spacecraft using gravity assist. It might take quite some time, but if the crew is determined...

Comment: The gravity-assist stop is highly dependent on how many orbiting bodies you have to play with as well. The book _Aurora_ went into detail about this (handwaved *to a degree* so that it wasn't technical), but there came a point when the ship's AI could not calculate an intercept with another massive body with the remaining fuel on board. The ship had slowed down *enough* that the humans on board were able to disembark (albeit with still dangerous levels of deceleration) before it went on its merry way out of the solar system. Mind, it spent *50+ years* doing this: the n-body problem is HARD.

Answer (score 5):

### Genetic control

The first matter to deal with is to ask what level of genetic modification is possible. If we are limited by standards *slightly* more advanced than today's, then we have a few options. We can..

Reduce or remove the production of certain [catecholamines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catecholamine), deflating some riot situations.

Reduce or remove the production of [serotonin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serotonin), causing memory loss. (What was i angry about?)

Modifying the image of a "perfect being." More specifically, giving a genetic bias towards a certain leader figure. Studies have shown that [completely irrelevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heights_of_presidents_and_presidential_candidates_of_the_United_States) genetic traits have contributed to public image. So what if the perfect match *happens* to be the current ship captain.

#### Kind of genetic

There is the ability to genetically hamper the supply of [insulin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin#Diseases_and_syndromes) to artificially administer diabetes. This could *very* quickly nip rebellions in the bud if the only insulin supplies are located at secure nodes.

In the same way, albeit somewhat less cruel, get everyone on a certain drug and watch as rebellions struggle through withdrawal before crawling back in surrender. (Never mind, just as cruel)

#### Other

Rather than using genetics (a recipe for some resistant hero to arrive), use neuroscience. As soon as someone gives birth, transport the newborn to a government approved "educational" site, guaranteed to improve IQ by *looks in PR folder* 20%. What is actually happening is basic [conditioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_conditioning). While curbing any rebellious thoughts for the next 2-3 years, the young will be fed direct associations between rebellion and pain, and conversely be given compliance and reward. As an added bonus, anyone audacious enough to not put their newborn through this *liberating* process will have the child labeled as being in possession of a lower intelligence.

Comment: I think that "other" part is the most realistic. Some studies show that observing the behaviour of kids in their first years, together with DNA studies, indicate a probability that they could turn violent. A la Minority Report. This is probably the safest route, assuming those techniques have improved.

Answer (score 4):

Why bother with genetics? Instill the importance of the mission into future generations with education. Raise it to the level of religion if necessary. It's certainly cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

Harry Harrison's *Captive Universe* had an interesting approach to this:
Split the population into two separate groups, engineered for low intelligence / docility , not allowed to interbreed during the voyage, but set up so that when they're allowed to interbreed on arrival, the children will have normal intelligence. The passengers don't know they're on a generation ship, and the crew had a monastic culture designed to discourage changes.

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_Universe)

Comment: Just put the two groups on separate spaceships. (Plot twist the two spaceships end up on different planets.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are firmly set on using genetics, you can take a look at **[novelty seeking](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Novelty_seeking)** and associated genes.

Novelty seeking is a personality trait associated with behaviours you want to restrict in your crew: curiosity, asocial attitudes, risk-taking, impulsiveness. People who demonstrate low levels of novelty seeking are perfect working bees. They tend to have highly developed [conscientiousness](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Conscientiousness), high preference for risk aversion, and introverted behavioural patterns. The downside is that they are less creative or flexible.

There is a caveat. Novelty seeking is important for psychological well-being and overall satisfaction with life. Therefore, you cannot get rid of it completely.

There is some evidence that novelty seeking is linked to the Dopamine receptor D4 gene on chromosome 11, specifically the length of its alleles. If you find a way to regulate this you might end up with a perfectly suitable colonist: Not too adventurous, but not docile either.

Comment: The problem is all those behaviors are also things you want is a colony crew. A crew adverse to novelty are never going to leave the colony ship.

Answer (score 2):

Run behavioral tests on people on Earth.  Select for whatever traits you want in your crew members both during the voyage and when you colonize.  Take gene samples of the people with the most favorable traits (i.e. docility and work ethic for ship crew, curiosity and aggressiveness for colonists) and add them to a genetic library.

Then you can launch your ship and for every "in vitro" fertilization, you can use CRISPR to edit the fetus's genome to be one from the library (or just have frozen cloned eggs available).  As long as the library size is well over twice the maximum expected population, and always processed in the same order, two genetic clones of the same library element won't be alive at the same time.  When you establish a colony, you can resume natural breeding techniques.

For extra insurance, you could run long-term trail runs of the ship with cloned crew close to Earth (or a simulator) to verify they won't rebel.  If you find some subset of the clones do rebel, remove them from the library and run another trial.

The advantage of this approach over minor direct gene editing is that it doesn't have to account for unexpected complex interactions in the genes of a single human.  Therefore it is less likely to have unexpected consequences.  It's also repeatable.

**Notes:**

1. I think there are serious ethical implications to human cloning and editing the genes of humans pre-birth, not to mention forcing generations to exist in interstellar space without their consent. I see these as forms of human-sacrifice, slavery, and [eugenics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenics), which might make this world an interesting dystopia.
2. A rebellion could take another form.  One of the most basic tenets of moral thinking is The Golden Rule: Treat others the way you like to be treated.  The ship inhabitants may resent having been created only to form a reproduction link from the Earth to the Colony. They may not want to impose the same fate on future generations.  To prevent this they may go on a birth-strike and refuse to reproduce.  Luckily, trait selection for cloning should work to prevent this as well.  There are plenty of people who are irrationally optimistic with low moral reasoning.

Comment: the big problem is separating genetic traits, cultural traits, and developmental traits, when selecting your population. Humans don't have a lot of genetic diversity, your average human has the genes to be a rapist and sociopath or to be a selfless paragon of virtue. upbring has a huge impact.

Comment: @John Studies of identical twins separated at birth show they mostly have similar personalities.  For an average upbringing of two identical clones, is it really just the flap of a butterfly's wings that separates the most virtuous from the most criminal?

Comment: keep in mind studies like that need to control for similar upbringing, butterfly's wings is a misunderstanding of what upbringing is. Socialization and culture have a huge impact.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make them intellectually disabled? The crew aren't exactly crew. they are more like cargo. They aren't necessary for maintaining the ship or directing it, they just need to sit quietly and not make a mess. So, make them docile simpletons. Mild intellectual disability will allow them to eat and reproduce and not much else. They won't have the ambition or the ability to redirect or destroy the ship. We know of lots of genetic disorders that cause intellectual disability. Down's syndrome could be used, or perhaps William's syndrome since that specifically impairs visuospacial reasoning. Once you reach the destination you can fix the disorders in the new children and have a normal colony. Just remember to round all the sharp corners on the ship and put child safety locks on the airlocks.

Comment: But when they get onto the planet, how will they survive?

Comment: @Jimmy360, they don't need to survive on the planet, the disabled humans are only breeding stock.  They are the biological component of a colonization machine, intended to provide a cheap method to give birth to the "colonists", who are the last generation (pre-touchdown) of humans to be born on the ship, from the bank of alread-fertilized eggs to be implanted into female breeders. (For that matter, why include males at all?)

Comment: Anyway, I'd expect that whatever "affected" humans were still alive at colonization time to remain on the ship after colonization. The change of environment would be enormously stressful for them, and the ship would be a reasonable old folks home.

Comment: This will not work since intellectually challenged colonists will not be able to raise fully-functioning children. Machines cannot replace humans as caregivers unless they are indistinguishable from humans. But then, why bother with human cargo in the first place? Just vat-grow humans once a colony is established and ready for fragile organic beings...

Answer (score 1):

### Artificial Wombs

There is not really much to do between point A and point B.  In fact, there is so little to do that you don't really need a crew to get to Epsilon Eridani.  Any course corrections needed to get there will be so trivial that a computer can do it for you. In fact, all you really need those 100 or so people for is when you arrive at the planet to start colonizing it.

While a fully developed human being is hard to put into stasis for 250 years, human reproductive cells can be frozen indefinitely using today's technology and still produce viable offspring.  Not only is this cheaper than adult stasis technology.  It is cheaper than supporting a live crew for all that time too.

Also, since you mentioned that stasis technology was cut due to budget reasons, it suggests that adult statis DOES exist in your setting.  So, instead of sending 100 adults in stasis, you instead use your slashed budget to send just 4-5 people in stasis.  Then 20 years before landfall, you wake them up and start growing your test tube babies (maybe about 10 per year). Your small handful of adults would then have to raise and educate them.  Yes, this sounds like a lot of babies per captia, but would be somewhat eased by the fact your adults don't need jobs, and many common household tasks can be automated with a little bit of robotics.  Since all of your next generation is born so close to thier destination, everyone born during the trip will arrive at the target world with no need to change course... in fact, they will be so close to thier destination, it will likely be too late to change course even if they wanted to.  So when you arrive on planet, you will have ~100 grown colonists: age 10-20 and 4-5 Earthlings age 40-50 to lead them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This option isn't exactly what you asked for but it would contribute to the end goal you trying to achieve - with a certain genetic flair.

**All Female crew for the flight duration**:
If you can freeze enough male eggs and female eggs, you could artificially fertilize the woman to only have female children for the duration of the trip. Woman tend to be less rebellious and boisterous then men, so this is a low effort genetic "manipulation" to help keep the crew in line :p